# Finding specific xpath conditioned to text-length Python Selenium

Tags: python, string, selenium, xpath

To get the correct content I desire within many, many pages - I have come up with a rule that works 99% of the time:

```
//a[@class='popular class' and not (contains(text(),'text1')) and not (contains(text(),'text2'))]
```

The other 1% results in finding more than 1 matching node, and requires more special treatment of "`not (contains(text(), 'specialtext'))`

What I figured out, is that the value I desire has only 1 character and up to a maximum of 4, while the special treatment cases will always exceed 4 digits.

What I'm trying to do is to add another condition in my xpath that would look like this:

```
//a[@class='popular class' and not (contains(text(),'text1')) and not (contains(text(),'text2')) and (text_length() < 5)]
```

This should work as a 100% rule that will always get me the specific node I need.
I have seen something equivalent in Java:

```
System.out.println("Select elements which 
  have string length less than 4");
  expr = xpath.compile(".//*[string-length(name()) < '4']")
```

[(From this website)](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/xPath/using-stringlengthXPath.shtml)

But couldn't find a matching function with Python.

Is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[string-length()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/string-length) is not a `Java` function, but an `XPath` function! You can use in the same way in your expression:

```
//a[@class='popular class' and not (contains(text(),'text1')) and not (contains(text(),'text2')) and string-length(.) < 5]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works as desired